# How to reverse the order of `<label>` and `<input>` in UIKIT3

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, getuikit

How to reverse the order of `<label>` and `<input>` in UIKIT? I have done the same in Bootstrap defining another close and placing this code.

```
.form-group-inline{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

I have tried the same in **UIKIT**, but I did not get the result I wanted.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: add      `label {order:-1;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can display flex and use .uk-flex-first and .uk-flex-last classes.

```
<div class="uk-flex">
  <label class="uk-flex-last"></label>
  <input class="uk-flex-first">
</div>
```